# Difference between SQL Server IN Operator with query and IN Operator with Value

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a query which gives me strange result or i am doing something wrong. I am using **IN** operator in **where** clause. I revive **country_id**(nullable),**province_id** (nullable) and city_id(nullable) from application. If **city_id** is not null then i extract all **centre_id** that exist in that **city_id** and stored in temp table. If **city_id** is null and province_id is not null then i extract all **centre_id** that exist in that **province_id** and in the same way if **city_id** and **province_id** both are null then i extract **centre_id** that exist in **country_id** and if all 3 are null then i extract all **centre_id** and stored in temp table like below:

```
DECLARE @serviceCenter TABLE (service_center_id INT)

    IF (@city_id IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @serviceCenter
        SELECT service_centre_id
        FROM ServiceCentre
        WHERE city_id= @city_id
    END
    ELSE IF (@province_id IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @serviceCenter
        SELECT service_centre_id
        FROM ServiceCentre
        INNER JOIN City ON City .city_id= ServiceCentre.city_id
        INNER JOIN Province ON Province.province_id= City.province_id
        WHERE Province.province_id= @province_id 
    END
    ELSE IF (@country_id IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @serviceCenter
        SELECT service_centre_id
        FROM ServiceCentre
        INNER JOIN City ON City .city_id= ServiceCentre.city_id
        INNER JOIN Province ON Province.province_id= City.province_id
        INNER JOIN Country ON Country.country_id= City.country_id
        WHERE Country.country_id = @country_id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @serviceCenter
        SELECT service_centre_id
        FROM ServiceCentre
    END
```

Now on the basis of **service centers** i need to get transaction count like below.

```
**Select Count(1)
From Tranactions
where service_centre_id IN (Select service_centre_id From @serviceCenter)**
```

Now the problem is this query gives the all transactions from all center_id. I checked it. If there is only one id in temp table and value is 1 it gives me all transactions. And when i run below query with hard code value, it gives the correct result

```
**Select Count(1)
    From Tranactions
    where service_centre_id IN (1)**
```

What's the different between  **where service_centre_id IN (Select service_centre_id From @serviceCenter)** and  **where service_centre_id IN (1)**.
What's the problem?

Comment: That should work.   Something else is going on.

Comment: Yeah this should work but i don't know what's wrong with this query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this query fetch all service_center_id:

`@serviceCenter` must be a table name.

> where center_id IN (Select service_centre_id From @serviceCenter)

and the another one is just select only contains 1 service_center_id

> where center_id IN (1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is not this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can severely simplify this query by using [COALESCE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), as such:

```
INSERT INTO @serviceCenter
SELECT COALESCE(City.service_centre_id,Provice.service_centre_id,Country.service_centre_id,ServiceCentre.service_centre_id)
FROM ServiceCentre
LEFT JOIN City 
    ON City.city_id = ServiceCentre.city_id
    AND City.City_ID = @city_id
LEFT JOIN Province 
    ON Province.province_id = City.province_id
    AND Province.province_id = @province_id 
LEFT JOIN Country 
    ON Country.country_id = City.country_id
    AND Country.country_id = @country_id
;
```

Each `JOIN` here uses the proper table joins, together with the parameter condition you want matched.  Because we're using `LEFT JOIN`, any condition that isn't matched will return a `NULL` value from that table.

The `COALESCE()` function takes a list of expressions and returns the first one that isn't `NULL`, so by ordering the expressions within the `COALESCE()` function to you're liking, you can tell it, "Try to bring me the City.service_centre_id first, then the Province.service_centre_id, then the Country.service_centre_id..." and so on.

Judging from what you're describing, I'm wondering if the problem isn't in the values being passed into the query in the parameters.  If you can write it out manually:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM Tranactions
WHERE center_id IN (1)
;
```

and this gives you the right result, then the problem is probably in the value being passed.

The end of your original query:

```
INSERT INTO @serviceCenter
SELECT service_centre_id
FROM ServiceCentre
;
```

seems to pass all service_centre_id values into the @serviceCenter variable.

Is it possible that the parameters aren't being passed properly, and thus all service_center_ids are being selected into the table variable, which would then cause you to receive a count of all transactions for all servicecenters?

**Note:** To check this, you can run a simple `SELECT * FROM @serviceCenter` at the end of your `IF...ELSE` series to see what values are returned.  My suspicion is that you'll get a few more than what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All parameters are being passed properly.

Comment: Hey Umer.  I'm sorry to be stubborn about this, but semantically there is zero difference between the two `SELECT` statements, unless the values are actually different.  Something else is causing this problem - it is not a technical difference between the two `SELECT` alternatives.  If the only value in @serviceCenter = 1, then they are identical; the only other expalanation is that the values in @serviceCenter are different.

Comment: This should work but the values in @serviceCenter is same. Something is going wrong. I will let you know when i will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 2 hours i found the mistake and mistake was nothing except the spell mistake. First of all i apologize because in question i used center_id but it was actually **service_centre_id**. However i updated the question. Now come to the problem. The declaration of the table was below:

```
**DECLARE @serviceCenter TABLE (service_center_id INT)
```

and the where clause was below:

```
Select Count(1)
From Tranactions
    where service_centre_id IN (Select service_centre_id From @serviceCenter)
```

The problem was in **service_centre_id** .

The transactions table contains the column **service_centre_id** and in IN operator query i was using **service_centre_id** instead of **service_center_id** . Because while declaring table i set the column name as **service_center_id**. So the actual mistake was i was using **service_centre_id** instead of **service_center_id** and there was spell mistake.